# undefined name in function 'redirect'

Tags: python, django

any advice on whats the problem? Im learning from a Django v1 tutorial, ive had a look at the documentation but cannot figure it out.

imports:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from accounts.forms import RegistrationForm
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserChangeForm
```

function:

```
def edit_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserChangeForm(request.POST instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/account/profile')
    else:
        form = UserChangeForm(instance=request.user)
        args = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'accounts/edit_profile.html', args)
```

thanks

Comment: First, indentation appears to be wrong. Second, where are your imports?

Comment: ..thirdly, where is your traceback?

Comment: `from django.shortcuts import render, redirect`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: @JShen. You did not provide the traceback as well as directly executable code in your question. If you want answer, you should do the effort to provide question that follow the standard of SO (That you should have read when creating your profile).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import `redirect` from `django.shortcut` with

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
```

This is well documented in the [Django's shortcut documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect).